# Limit of sine function

Tags: limits

What is the $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt n/{n^{\sin n}}$$

I want to learn about the behavior of sine functions, I know it oscillates between 1 to -1 but I don't know how to represent it. Please give a detailed answer.

Regards

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add the upvote.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sqrt[n]{n^{\sin n}} = \exp\left(\frac{\log n}{n}\cdot\sin(n)\right)$$
but $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{\log n}{n}=0$ and $\left|\sin n\right|\leq 1$, hence the limit is $\exp(0)=\color{red}{1}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
Compute the limit of the logarithm of the expression first. You may use that $\sin n$ is bounded.